# What does "ground" mean as a verb here?

Tags: meaning

> People learn language through exposure to a rich perceptual context.
>   Language is **grounded** by mapping words, phrases, and sentences to
>   meaning representations referring to the world.

Does "ground" mean "give (something abstract) a firm theoretical or practical basis"? Thanks!

Comment: definition here [ground](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/ground) sense 16) "to found on a firm basis; establish"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you understand it perfectly.